# как занулить первые 4 бита в байте на java

Tags: java, hex

Предположим что есть байт b = 63. В битах это будет 0011 1111.
Как можно занулить первые 4 бита чтобы получилось 0000 1111?
Делаю чтобы можно было приводить байты к 16-ричной системе.
Для зануления последних 4х битов использую сдвиг >>.

Comment: `&= (byte) 0b00001111`

Comment: Можно byte = byte & 0x0F, а можно сдвиг влево, а потом вправо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы [из `0b0110_0010` получить `0b0000_0010`](https://ideone.com/k5LqGo), чтобы обнулить первые 4 бита, считая слева-направо (как люди на бумаге пишут):

```
b &= 0b0000_1111; // & 0x0f
```

Чтобы [из `0b0110_0010` получить `0b0000_0110`](https://ideone.com/lmrfvx), чтобы обнулить первые 4 бита, считая справа-налево:

```
b = (byte) ((b & 0b1111_0000) >> 4); // & 0xf0) >> 4
```

В данном случае нет разницы между `>>` и `>>>`.

Для байта легко напечатать все возможные значения, чтобы выбрать желаемое поведение слева или справа очищать биты.

---

Кстати: `63 == 0b0011_1111`, а не `0b0110_0010` и даже `0x63 == 0b0110_0011` не равно `0b0110_0010`.

Answer (score 4):

Используя, например, [побитовые операторы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/bitwise.php)

```
>>>=    Сдвиг вправо с заполнением нулями с присваиванием

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = 63;
    System.out.println(b);
    b >>>= 4;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Результат:

```
63
3
```

Comment: это [отсекает биты, считая справа](https://ideone.com/pSYaw1). Для `b < 0`: [бит знака  размножается](https://ideone.com/jlswN4).

Comment: бит знака размножается потому что byte в int превращается (слева 24 единицы как будто записываются для `b < 0`). Поэтому для задачи обнуления битов в байте всё равно что использовать `>>` или `>>>`. Т.к.  `>>> n` и `>> n` для byte ведёт себя одинаково (для 0 <= n <= 24).